# How to make a circle fill animation with Tailwind and React?

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css, css-animations, font-awesome

Im using Font Awesome with React and Tailwind and have these icons with some styles:

```
<FontAwesomeIcon
    icon={faFacebook}
    className="text-facebook bg-white rounded-full hover:text-white hover:bg-facebook transition-colors duration-300 ease-in-out"
    size="6x"
/>
```

However, I want to make an animation on hover like this gif with Tailwind:

[image: animation gif]

Does anyone have any clue on how to do this?

I have tried Layering methods with Font Awesome directly but I couldn't make it work.

Comment: Which font awesome NPM package are you using?